# While fetching public API of swiggyI am getting error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-frontend, developer-tools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQ6p8.png)

I am trying to fetch data from swiggy public API, for this I have added CORS extention to my chrome. I am using useEffect hook and calling my function in it, but when I run it is showhing **type error as failed to fetch**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.